# Google sheet Conditional formatting if text is in a list of words

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, conditional-formatting

How do I format a sheet so that the cells change according to the value inside a cell of a specific column that matches certain words?

For example:

Apply to range: A:F

Custom formula is: =F:F=("this", "is", "a", "set", "of", "words")

Then apply formatting style.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regexmatch()`, like this:

`=regexmatch($F:$F, "(?i)^(this|is|a|set|of|words)$")`

The formula will only match single words and will not match longer phrases that contain one of the words. To make it match such phrases, use this:

`=regexmatch($F:$F, "(?i)\b(this|is|a|set|of|words)\b")`

The `\b` pattern signifies a word boundary.

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: ...or if each cell contains only one word, and not a phrase with the specified word, then `=MATCH($F1,{"this", "is", "a", "set", "of", "words"},0)` is enough

Comment: As far as I understand, you have never used File-Download and have not encountered any possible problems?

Comment: I do not use Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If each cell contains only one word, and not a phrase with the specified word, then you can use

`=MATCH($F1,{"this", "is", "a", "set", "of", "words"},0)`

[image: Example]

Comment: To make it work with phrases, use `=match("*" & $F1 & "*", { "this", "is", "a", "set", "of", "words" }, 0)`.

Comment: But the word "a" can ruin everything - cat, car, gas will cause false alarms.

Comment: Yeah... problem is that the OP's actual requirements remain unknown. It is unlikely that the real use case calls for hard-coded text strings in the formula in the first place.